# Ubuntu 19.04 - Windows key logs me out

Tags: gnome, 19.04

I was having some visual bugs so I pressed ALT + F2 then typed r, now when I try to press the windows key to start a program after 2 presses it logs me out.

Comment: Something could crash. To get more information, you can run `dmesg` in the Terminal after this has happened and see if there are any errors.

Comment: I get
gnome-shell[2292]: segfault at 80 ip 00007fb241f79450 sp 00007ffd45409c48 error 4 in libst-1.0.so[7fb241f59000+2d000]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an extension that was broken called Workspace Grid and after I removed it the bug was gone. Thank you SurvivalMachine for the dmesg command it helped a lot.